# to make maven project to dynamic web project so that i can debug in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, circular-dependency

I am having 4 maven project they are **project_1, project_2, project_3, project_4**

here **project_1** is having **project_2** jar in its dependency along with other dependency jars

**project_2** is having **project_1** jar in its dependency along with other dependency jars

**project_3** is having **project_1** jar and **project_4** jar in its dependency along with other dependency jars

**project_4** is having **project_1** jar and **project_2** jar in its dependency along with other dependency jars.

The way i am running this project in wildfly is that i am putting all the **projects mvn clean install jar** inside DEMO.war of the wildfly

then i am deploying it and testing it .

i need convert this **maven project** to **dynamic web project** so that i can debug the project on eclipse how will i do it ?

Comment: From my view point , you need to re-engineer the application as your question clearly states cyclic dependency which is not desirable

Comment: @EspringDev is totally right. You need to resolve the cyclic dependency between project_1 and project_2 first.